# Docker error when running docker compose up

Tags: docker, terminal

When I run this in terminal:

```
docker compose up
```

I get this error:

> docker:desktop-linux unable to prepare context: path "" not found

I am 100% sure I am in the correct directory. I had it running before but after running compose down it no longer works.

Tried changing the location of yaml file along with accompanying folders, but this did nothing.

Here is my .yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  source_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - elt_network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: source_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./source_db_init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  destination_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    networks:
      - elt_network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: destination_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret

  elt_script:
    build:
      context: ./elt_script # Directory containing the Dockerfile and elt_script.py
      dockerfile: Dockerfile # Name of the Dockerfile, if it's something other than "Dockerfile", specify here
    command: [ "python", "elt_script.py" ]
    networks:
      - elt_network
    depends_on:
      - source_postgres
      - destination_postgres

networks:
  elt_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Directory structure:

```
~/docker_tutorial/ELT » tree                                                                       nita@caro
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── elt
│   ├── Dockerfile.webloc
│   └── elt_script.py
└── source_db_init
    └── init.sql

3 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: Please share your `docker-compose.yml` file with us.

Comment: added it to the original question.

Comment: What is your file / directory structure? (execute `tree` in the directory where you have your `docker-compose.yml`).

Comment: added it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The path in your context `./elt_script` does not exist according to the directory structure you provided. Try changing it to a directory that exists (i.e. `./elt`).